# Is there a way to invoke the GuiSize label programatically?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

`Gosub` does not let `A_GUI` and `A_GUIEvent` being accessed. `WinMove` and sending the message 0x03 to the window did not work.

I have some window adjustment routines in the GUISize label and when I use `GUIControl, Show/Hide` to a control, some rendering issues have occurred; the control does not appear. `WinSet, Redraw,` did not help. But if I resize the window manually and the GUISize label and its routines are called, it redraws fine.

So I'm looking for a way to trigger the GUI size label artificially. Is it possible?

```
Gui, New, hwndhwndGUI Resize 
Gui, Margin, 30, 30
Gui, Add, Text, w100, Hello World
Gui, Show, Center
Return
GuiSize:
    tooltip % A_GUI ", " A_GUIEvent
Return

^1::GoSub, GuiSize      ; A_GUI, A_GUIEvent are not sent 
^2::
    WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, ahk_id %hwndGUI%
    WinMove, X+1, Y, W+1, H, ahk_id %hwndGUI%   ; does not trigger the GUISize label.
Return
^3::SendMessage, 0x03,,,, ahk_id %hwndGUI%   ; does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this worked.

```
SendMessage, 0x05,,,, ahk_id %hwndGUI%
```